# Show that $x \in\mathbb Q$ then $x=p^nu$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

The localisation of $\mathbb{Z}$ at the prime ideal $(p)$ can be written  $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}= \left\{ \frac ab\in \mathbb Q\mid a,b\in \mathbb Z,p\nmid b \right\}$ with p a prime number. 
As an exercice, is it possible to show that if $x \in \mathbb{Q}$, then there exists a unique $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $x=p^nu$ where $u$ is an invertible element of $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$?

It's already possible to show that every ideal $I$ of the ring $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$, there exist a unique integer $n \geqslant 0$ such that $I$ is generated by $p^n$ ( every element of $I$ can be written as $p^n.u$ , $u \in \mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$).

But i'm not sure how to navigate between an element $\frac ab \in \mathbb{Q}$ and an ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\Bbb Z_{(p)}$ is an easy to understand ring, let us explicitly find its units. Notice that if $\dfrac a b \in \Bbb Z_{(p)}$ in lowest terms then

$$\exists \frac c d = \left( \frac a b \right)^{-1} \in \Bbb Z_{(p)} \implies ac = bd \implies p \nmid a$$

because $p \nmid d$ and $p \nmid d$.

Conversely, for $\dfrac a b \in \Bbb Z_{(p)}$, if $p \nmid a$ then $\dfrac b a \in \Bbb Z_{(p)}$, hence $\dfrac b a \dfrac a b = 1$, so $\dfrac a b$ is invertible in $\Bbb Z_{(p)}$

We get then that the units of $\Bbb Z_{(p)}$ are $\{\dfrac a b \in \Bbb Z_{(p)} \mid p \nmid a\}$.

Let now $\dfrac a b \in \Bbb Q$ be written in lowest terms. There exist unique numbers $m,n,a',b'$ such that $a = p^m a'$ and $b = p^n b'$, with $p\nmid a'$ and $p \nmid b'$, whence it follows that $\dfrac a b = p^{m-n} \dfrac {a'} {b'}$.

The uniqueness of this writing: assume there exist $s, t, a, b, c, d$ such that $p^s \dfrac a b = p^t \dfrac c d$ with $\dfrac a b, \dfrac c d \in \Bbb Z_{(p)}$ in lowest terms. It follows then that $p^{s-t} = \dfrac {bc} {ad}$. Since the units of a ring form a group, it follows that $\dfrac {bc} {ad}$ is invertible in $\Bbb Z_{(p)}$, so $p^{s-t} = \dfrac {p^{s-t}} 1$ is invertible in $\Bbb Z_{(p)}$ so, according to the description of the group of units that we have found above, it follows that $s=t$, so $\dfrac a b = \dfrac c d$, whence $a = c$ and $b = d$ because the fractions are in lowest terms. This proves uniqueness.

Comment: Thank you for the demonstration. The units of $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ is an ideal but it is seen here as a group. So contrary to what I though no ideal was required.

Comment: @Xaving: The units of $\Bbb Z_{(p)}$ do NOT form an ideal! Keep in mind that $1$ is a unit, and that an ideal containing $1$ is the whole ring. Since there are elements in $\Bbb Z_{(p)}$ that are not units (for instance $p$ itself), it follows that the units do not form an ideal.